# EF Context in Model Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

In our Web.API project, we use Entity Framework 6. We have a DataModel class, which contains the DatabaseContext. The DataModel is a `[ThreadStatic]` Singleton.

Like this:

```
public class DataModel
{
    [ThreadStatic] private static DataModel _instance;
    public static DataModel Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new DataModel());

    public DatabaseContext Context { get; private set; }

    private DataModel()
    {
        Context = NewContext();
    }
}
```

Now in one of our (partial) model classes, we use the context like this:

```
public partial class Job
{
    public User CreatedByUser
    {
        get { return DataModel.Instance.Context.Users.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Username == CreatedBy); }
    }
}
```

We search in another table in the database the corresponding user. This works, but in my opinion, this is not a beautiful solution. Especially if we plan to migrate our project to.NET Core and use dependency injection for the database context.

My Question is, is there a pattern, which solves the problem more elegant? Dependency injection won't work here because Entity Framework generates the model objects. Or would it be better, if we move this code from the partial class to e.g. a util class? But how can we inject there the context?

Comment: Both a singleton context and using contexts inside entity classes are anti-patterns. So first try to get rid of these patterns without worrying about DI yet. You'll see that after that, it'll be much easier to convert the code to DI. *How* to do this depends too much on the rest of your architecture to say anything sensible about it.

Comment: In what layer does this datamodel reside? Is it the model returned from the API, or an attempt at a database abstraction layer? Generally I'd suggest to use a repository pattern, but that doesn't fit all problems. Letting models populate themselves through database calls (the "active record pattern") generally causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: The use of proper Foreign Keys would solve the problem. Job is related by the CreatedBy user *on UserId* and not Username (unless username is the PK in your users table in which case you should rethink that). Map that relationship in EF and then you can navigate to the `CreatedByUser` using either lazy loading if the entity is attached OR retrieve it immediately using an `Include` clause in the query. Your current solution is not thread safe especially considering that you have an asp.net app which has multiple threads (1x simultaneous request at a minimum).

Comment: The job-model is created by the EF. We already talked about to use a foreign key, but we have decided against it. But now, it makes more sense to use it. We will fix the anti-pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to avoid requiring your models to have awareness of their creation and usage context since that knowledge should be top down and not bottom up. Among other reasons, you'll run into design issues like you are experiencing now. You can try to design your way around it at the application level with extension methods, an inversion of control framework, utility methods, pocos, etc, but at the end of the day you are trying to solve a problem that only exists because your underlying database schema is inadequately designed for your intended usage.

For example, your `Job` table has a reference to the username of the user that created it. Why? It might be possible for usernames to change and any time you want additional critical properties of that user you will need to perform a secondary lookup (like you're doing in your partial class). If you instead have the `Job` table maintain a foreign key to the `User` table, you can just use a navigation property on the C# side to get the full user object as long as the appropriate related entities are included in the query. You wouldn't even need the partial class and your database schema would become more maintainable as an added bonus.

Sometimes it's best to simplify the database design to simplify the code.